# Rx java error caught in a different room request

Tags: android, sql, rx-java2, android-room

I have an Android project with RxJava + Room setup.
Activity **A** launches activity **B**.
In both activities there are subscriptions to the Room database requests.

If there is empty response in request in activity **A** it works as supposed, but on activity B launch there is an error in the different room request.

**In activity A (observable on Maybe<>):**

```
viewModel.getClassesById(classesTaken)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnSuccess { list ->
                        if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
                            stats.initiate(student, list)
                        }
                    }
                    .defaultIfEmpty(arrayListOf())
                    .doOnError { it.printStackTrace() }
                    .subscribe()
```

**In activity B (subscription on a single):**

```
compositeDisposable.add(viewModel.studentsCount
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSuccess {
                students_total.text = it.toString()
            }
            .doOnError {
                students_total.text = "-"
            }
            .subscribe())
```

So the calls are separated and belong to different activities. How is this behaviour possible?

> ```
> Caused by: android.arch.persistence.room.EmptyResultSetException: Query returned empty result set: SELECT * FROM classes WHERE _id IN()
> ```
>
> ORDER BY date DESC
>       03-06 14:34:48.474 16675-16675/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.database.dao.StudentDAO_Impl$6.call(StudentDAO_Impl.java:345)
>       03-06 14:34:48.474 16675-16675/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog W/System.err:
>   at
>   com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog.database.dao.StudentDAO_Impl$6.call(StudentDAO_Impl.java:327)
>       03-06 14:34:48.474 16675-16675/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog W/System.err:
>   at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:44)
>       03-06 14:34:48.474 16675-16675/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog W/System.err:
>   at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
>       03-06 14:34:48.474 16675-16675/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog W/System.err:
>   at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
>       03-06 14:34:48.474 16675-16675/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog W/System.err:
>   at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:463)
>       03-06 14:34:48.474 16675-16675/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog W/System.err:
>   at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
>       03-06 14:34:48.474 16675-16675/com.labfoodandfriends.nikitagudkovs.jlog W/System.err:
>   at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)

Comment: can you add the definitions of `classesTaken` and `studentsCount`? Given that you are saying that there's a `Single` involved in `studentsCount`, I suspect that this is the expected behavior: a query that is expected to return `Single` throws an exception if there's no data that matches

Comment: @marianosimone Thank you for your comment. Yet - how can returning a wrong set of information be an expected behaviour? If there's an error - that should end up in the error branch and not return anything. Isn't it so?

Comment: I can't follow the logic 100% with so much missing code (definitions of those queries, and how A launches B). You say that activity B is the one failing, but the exception shows a query that is more likely to be from A. Can you add some more context?